# How to use domain controller in Server parameter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Using PowerShell script, I am getting a valid hostname using the `Get-ADDomainController` command as following:

```
$domainController = (Get-ADDomainController -DomainName 'mydomain.local' -Discover).hostname;
```

After having defined my credentials, I would like to use the retrieved hostname in the Server parameter of my `Get-ADUser` command:

```
$User = Get-ADUser -Identity 'accountName' -Server $domainController -Credential $mycred;
```

However, the code fails and the prompted error looks like:

> Cannot convert Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection into String

Could you please give any insights on how to convert that value into String?

Comment: if `$domainController` is a collection, then you can access the first member through an index: `$domainController[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when doing a network redundancy is a big deal. If a domain controller were to go down then no one would be able to authenticate. many apps use AD for authentication and permission (usually based on group) which would make alot of apps unusable.

Lets take a look at what Microsoft has to say about [Get-AdDomainController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-addomaincontroller?view=win10-ps).

This line sticks out *"Gets one or more Active Directory domain controllers"*

This sounds like it will return a collection of **Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADDomainController** objects.

So there are a few ways to get a single domain

```
$domainController = get-addomaincontroller -DomainName 'mydomain.local' -Discover) | Select hostname -first 1;
```

or

```
($domainController = get-addomaincontroller -DomainName 'mydomain.local' -Discover)[0].Hostname
```

There are more ways but i hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer that solved my issue. I was also expecting this object to be an array even if it only gets one domain.

Comment: Thank you Adrien :)